# Net Profiles caused trouble in Firefox proxy settings

Tags: proxy, connection, firefox

Last week I tried [Net Profiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) to switch between my connection settings (DNS, proxy etc.) easier but then I decided to uninstall the program. After uninstallation, I realized that Firefox connection settings are always automatically switched to `No Proxy`. Now I have to change it to `Automatic Proxy Configuration URL` option manually every time I start Firefox. I guess this behavior was caused by the uninstalled program *Net Profiles*. How can I correct this?

Screenies:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution:

1. I re-installed Net Profiles. My
   previous profiles were there.
2. Then I deleted them all.
3. I created a new profile and in that
   profile, I clicked on "Clear settings
   for Firefox".
4. I opened Firefox' connection
   settings and selected my "Automatic
   proxy configuration URL".
5. In Net Profiles, I clicked on "Get current
   settings".
6. I uninstalled Net Profiles.
7. I restarted Firefox, and
   the problem is solved. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

This is  a known Net Profiles error, the official workaround (one simpler than reinstalling Net Profiles) can be found here:

http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/issues/detail?id=26

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. U can temporarily fix it in Internet Tab in Network Profiles. Just click the Clear Firefox Settings button. Then U should have rights to edit proxy settings in browser.